# sniffing http headers on an embedded device

Tags: http, header, tcpdump

Is there any light weight tools which can filter and output http headers/responses in human readable form? Something like wireshark. I have tried tcpdump; but it is hard to read.

Comment: On what devices? You could also sniff the traffic on a proxy if you can make the device connect to one.

Comment: On a mips linux which is stripped down to bone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you able to configure proxy settings on the embedded device you can (like in web browser) you can be very flexible. I like for example Fiddler tool http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/. If you start fiddler tool on you "normal" computer with Windows 7/XP etc, fiddler runs as a proxy with a port (typically 8888). If you configure on the embedded device IP address with this port as a proxy, you will see or be able generate auto-responses etc. inside of fiddler of your computer.

So you can solve the problem without installation on embedded device any software.

I don’t want to write a long text here, but I recommend watching video http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/CL25, where Fiddler developer Eric Lawrence explains Fiddler’s features.

Comment: I like the proxy idea, but I want to see debug messages on the same console. However if I dont get a better answer, I will accept this.

Comment: If you able configure a proxy, just try fiddler and look at results. If you took a little time and study fiddler features, for example, from the vidio (see my answer) you will be don't look at any other tool. I like fiddler and use it permanently. Together with different addons it is even more powerful.